# When is the gradient direction of an image more useful than the magnitude?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, gradient

Are there real-world problems or situations where the directional gradients of an image Gx and Gy are more useful than its magnitude sqrt(Gx^2 + Gy^2)? For some intuition, if required, please see [matlab image gradient](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/imgradient.html)

Answer (score 2):

The gradient information is guaranteed to be perpendicular to image (and more generally grey levels) contours. Thus, it is related to the geometry of the objects in an image, not to their "color". As such, it is an information that is independent from the actual luminance value of any pixel, it depends only on their relative distribution. This is also coined as **contrast-change-invariant measure**.

Contrast changes are very likely to occur in real world applications.
Take for example a video surveillance system: during the day, the sun will move over the horizon, clouds can fly by, causing the light intensity to change. A system that detects gradient orientation changes instead of pixel value of gradient magnitude changes will be more robust to these illumination changes.

More generally, gradient direction, unlike its magnitude, is closely related to the vast field of [image morphology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology) that is very useful in shape recognition context.

Comment: Nice answer. Just wanted to add that the contrast-change-invariance holds only if the change is global.

Answer (score 1):

A number of real world problems are easier to solve when considering the x and y gradients separately. Although many of these will be very specialised one that comes to mind is sky line detection. An edge detector that gives preference (or only uses information) from the yGradient can distinguish the horizon line much easier.

Pretty much anything that has to detect edges that run in one particular direction can make use of a separate x and y gradient. Although I can't think of many examples off the top of my head I'm pretty sure I read a paper a while ago on automatic inspection of fill levels for bottles which made full use of the vertical gradient while suppressing the horizontal.

In my own work I've written a few edge detection algorithms to detect horizontal layering in borehole images, which assigns a greater weight to the vertical gradient than the horizontal. This suppresses drilling marks and caliper arm shadows while enhancing the mostly horizontal layers.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use it when you would like anisotropic (direction-dependent) filters; like you would like to filter object with edges only in a specific orientation.

Answer (score 0):

A Hough transform for shape detection (e.g. lines, circles etc) can be made more efficient by considering edge orientation; for example, see these lecture slides I just found: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/MORSE/hough.pdf